# Why manually calculated MSE different from LassoCV.mse_path in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm working with lasso in python, but there is a question which confuses me.
In the following [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_lasso_model_selection.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-lasso-model-selection-py), my codes are as follows:

```
kf = KFold(10,random_state=0,shuffle=False)  
model_lassocv = LassoCV(cv=kf).fit(X, y)
```

And the model_lassocv.mse_path_ gives array([[ 5747.95194531,  4590.75732123, ...]]).

I manually calculated the mse:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict, cross_val_score
lasso = linear_model.Lasso(alpha = model_lassocv.alphas_[0])
predict = cross_val_predict(lasso, X, y, cv=kf)
metrics.mean_squared_error(y_pred=predict[0:44],y_true=y[0:44]) 
# 0:44 is the first test set according to KFold function
# and result here gives 5625 instead of 5747.95
```

However,

```
cross_val_score(lasso,X,y, cv=kf, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error")
```

gives the same except negative result as  model_lassocv.mse_path_.

Sorry for my misleading question. I'm wondering why `metrics.mean_squared_error` returns a different result from `mse_path_`. If I'm not misunderstanding the partition for `KFold`, the first test set in 10-fold CV is 0:44. And the MSE of cross-validated prediction and true values in the first test set for the first alpha (2.14804358 in my case) calculated by `metrics.mean_squared_error` returns 5625, whereas the `mse_path_` of LassoCV returns 5747.

Comment: Could you put an example for X and Y so we can check the results?

Comment: I believe this is discussed here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2439

I think if you want the two to match, use `make_scorer` and pass `greater_is_better = True`

Comment: Well, the `mse_path_` attribute provides the MSE across the different alphas that were tested during the modeling process. You would have to find what alpha was selected by the model and then find the corresponding MSE for that alpha value. As for the negative value of MSE, that's just how the developers designed it. That's why the scoring is called `neg_mean_squared_error`. In previous versions of sklearn, the `neg` was not in the scoring description which resulted in confusion for users.

Comment: @Mabel Villalba  I'm sorry, but the example is provided in the link below.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr  I've got your message, but there may be a misleading in the question. I'm ok with the result of  neg_mean_squared_error and mse_path_, they are the same. The MSE calculated by myself is using the first alpha in the lassoCV result, and this MSE is supposed to be 5747.95194531 (for the first alpha and for the first test set in 10-fold CV).  However I get 5625. That's what confusing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is in your manual implementation of fitting the model. The MSE in the `mse_path_` attribute is the MSE for each of the folds generated by your KFold object. However, in your manual implementation, when you use `cross_val_predict`, you are asking sklearn to train a model with all available folds, rather than the specific fold that was used in your LassoCv implementation. I'll provide the right solution using the boston dataset provided by sklearn.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict, cross_val_score, KFold
from sklearn.linear_model import LassoCV, Lasso
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)
kf = KFold(10, random_state=0, shuffle=False)
```

Now let's see what folds look like:

```
for train_i, test_i in kf.split(X):
    print(train_i, test_i)

(array([ 51,  52,  53, ... , 505], dtype=int64), array([ 0,  1,  2, ... , 50], dtype=int64)) ... (array([ ... ]))
```

For brevity, I just show the first fold, where the training set consists of index from 51 to 505, and for the test set in this fold, the index is from 0 to 50.

Now let's fit using your LassoCV approach:

```
model_lassocv = LassoCV(cv=kf).fit(X, y)
model_lassocv.mse_path_
```

Result of the MSE path:

```
  array([[  41.74173819,   29.78409579,   32.00672122,  191.68560655,
           103.46618603,  172.62108062,   16.92365434,  181.06822315,
           116.83656233,   35.92813347], [ ... ], ... ])
```

Again, for brevity, I only show the MSE of all the 10 folds for the first alpha. Based on your example, you want to match the MSE of the first fold of the first alpha used in your LassoCV, so in my case, I want to manually get a result = 41.74173819.

Now, here is what I would do with my manual implementation:

```
  lasso = Lasso(alpha = model_lassocv.alphas_[0])
  lasso.fit(X[51:506], y[51:506])
  predict = lasso.predict(X[0:51])
  mean_squared_error(y_pred=predict, y_true=y[0:51])
```

Key differences:

1. I fit my model using training set of the 1st fold identified by the KFold object (remember how I said the first fold training had index from 51-505?).
2. Then I generate my predictions based on the test set of the 1st fold. (here, the index for the test set was from 0-50)

Result of my manual calculation?

41.741738189299873

Hence, we have a match.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I made a mistake in selecting the test set index in my example. And your solution did help a lot.